# A11y for empty anchor tag

Tags: html, css, accessibility, anchor

Our site currently has a component which is implemented by using an `<a>` tag with a "background" image that is set by using

```
a.class-name::after {
    content: url('image.png');
}
```

The tag itself has no content (looks like `<a class="class-name" other-attrs></a>`). The problem I have is that we need to add the equivalent of an alt-text to this link. Since anchor tags do not support the `alt` attribute, I can think of two options:

1. Put the alt-text inside the tag, and then style it so the text doesn't show up. The problem is that I'm not sure that this will be picked up by a screen reader, since it might detect that it's invisible.
2. Put the alt-text in the `title` attribute of the tag. Although `title` is normally ignored by screen readers, I read [here](https://silktide.com/i-thought-title-text-improved-accessibility-i-was-wrong/) that "the only very tiny exception a title attribute will be read is if there’s absolutely no link anchor text, and that’s rare". For us, this is *precisely* the case, but I want to double check with more knowledgeable people that this really would work.

Perhaps there is an even better third option? In any case, any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: https://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/

Comment: @CBroe thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keep it simple.  Just add an [`aria-label`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-label) attribute to the anchor.

`<a class="class-name" aria-label="text you want read by screen reader"></a>`

Answer (score 4):

If you have a content image, use a content image:

```
<a ...><img src="image.png" alt="..."></a>
```

Leave background images for *backgrounds*.

Comment: The problem is that I want the image to change on the hover event. It's much easier to do this when the image is set by a CSS property.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a `<span>` tag inside `<a>`:

```
<a href=""><span class="sr-only sr-only-focusable">alt text</span></a>
```

And CSS for the classes:

```
.sr-only {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 0;
}

.sr-only-focusable:active, .sr-only-focusable:focus {
  position: static;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  overflow: visible;
  clip: auto;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

The above style was taken from Bootstrap. You can also look for H5BP or WordPress to see what their methods are, all very similar in general.

Then apply your other style as normal. But I suggest to use `background` over pseudo elements, as you won't be able to control the image size with `content: url()`.

Comment: The `span.sr-only` approach is sufficient to provide a text-alternative which satisfies WCAG 1.1.1 Non-text Content.

Comment: The `.sr-only-focusable` class isn't necessary to satisfy WCAG 1.1.1 Non-text Content.  The main use for this class is completely invisible links (without an image), such as a "skip-to-main-content" link which sighted keyboard-users rely on.   In @Stickers answer, it is doing the job of a keyboard-operable tooltip, rather than an image text alternative.  You don't always need both behaviours.